# How to display events in the calendar using Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, events, calendar

I am building a calendaring application in ruby on rails. I am using my own schema for storing events,  but I don't know how to display events in calendar, and also how to add a calendar in my application.

Will I have to write code to display calendar or can I use any plugin to display calendar.

Answer (score 5):

I think the [calendar_helper plugin](http://topfunky.net/svn/plugins/calendar_helper/) is what you want.  It provides a calendar method to your views, which can be called to generate a month-view calendar in HTML.

You can pass it a block which builds the contents of each day's cell, which is where you would want to do whatever your event schema requires to pull in the day's events.

Answer (score 3):

The EventCalendar plugin was created for this very reason. Easily show multiple, overlapping events across calendar days and rows.

http://github.com/elevation/event_calendar

Screenshot(s) at: http://dev.elevationblog.com/2009/7/23/event-calendar-rails-plugin

Answer (score 1):

There's a little list of candidates [here](http://code.google.com/p/calendardateselect/).

The plugin on the page itself seems to offer some AJAX goodness, if that's something you're interested in.

Answer (score 1):

I also had to build a calendar in rails. None of the existing calendar gems appealed to me as they did too much. I wanted to render the calendar myself so I could control the styling. I also had an existing Event model so I didn't need any kind of event handling. I ended up creating [the cal gem](https://github.com/austinthecoder/cal). It's pretty straightforward when you look at the README. I plan to improve it to have weekly and daily calendars. Good luck!